# UART doesn't receive all sent values in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, uart

I'm triying to send data from a PSoc via UART to my PC where a want to store data with Qt. The PSoc sends 3 bytes of data. Theses 3 bytes are repeatet with a frequency of 2.5Hz. When I check the signals with my oscilloscope everything is fine. When I receive the data with the software HTerm also everything is as expected. When I use my code written in c++ with Qt I get the problem that not all data are received in Qt, only one third is in the memory. I expected that the signal readyRead is emitted with every new byte? But it seems that the signal is only emitted at the begin of the package of the 3 bytes. Also my qDebug output doesn't react on changes from the PSoc. So when I change values at PSoc the output in qDebug doesn't change.

I already tried reading 3 Bytes (serial->read(3)) and then I first received some single bytes and after a few readings I get the 3 bytes I sended but this is not so reproducible.

```
    connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));

    serial->setPortName(gui->ui->comboBox->currentData().toString());
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    void uart::readData()
    {
        QByteArray data = serial->read(1); 
        qDebug() << data;
    }
```

I expect an output like "0x01" "0x02" "0x03" 2.5 times a second, but I get only "0x01"

Comment: I recommend that you read [the `readyRead` reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead). It's emitted for new data, not for every byte. If there's multiple byte received you will get only one signal.

Comment: I already read this but I'm not sure what they mean with "new" data. How can I decide between receiving one byte as new data or several bytes. This would mean that Qt uses some sort of time base.

Comment: On a preemptive operating system (like the big three PC operating systems are) then you have no control over when your program gets a chance to run. While the operating system have preempted it and letting some other process run, there might arrive multiple characters on the serial port. And when your process and your program starts running again only *one* `readyRead` event will be emitted, no matter how many bytes have been received since last event. You should always be ready to handle multiple bytes in your function.

Comment: Yes your right I think. This is a scheduler problem. It's no problem to write a function filtering the wrong data packages out. But is there an other solution for this because other programs like HTerm can also handle this and receive all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution!
You have to set the read-buffer size to the right value.
So for reading a package of three bytes I must set:

```
serial->setReadBufferSize(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only reading a fixed size with read.

Could it be that you get readyRead signals with varying bytes available but you only read fixed size of them

In your readyRead slot try to read all available bytes.

```
qint64 available = serial->bytesAvailable();
if (available > 0)
{
    QByteArray data = serial->read(available);
    qDebug() << data;
}
```

You can also use readAll() function.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Unfortunately there's no difference using your solution. I've got still the problem that there is sometimes only one byte in the buffer where it has to be three bytes, as I discribed in the comment above.